# Автоматизация добавление контента на сайт Bitrix

Tags: java, веб-программирование, битрикс

Есть задача заполнять позиции товара добавленного на сайт построенный на CMS битрикс. Позиции с названиями уже созданы на сайте, но они не имеют описания и картинки. У меня есть PDF файлы которые я средствами Java распарсил на изображение и описание. Есть ли API или какой другой способ обновлять контент на сайте ? чем проще тем лучше.

Comment: да можно прям в базу писать из пдф. Я так и делал, только источник был не пдф а SOAP сервис.

Comment: встроенным в битрикс апи получалось слишком долго, а конкретный ответ на ваш вопрос будет сильно зависеть от того, как этот ваш "контент" выглядит в битриксе.

Answer (score 2):

1. API есть. Ну, то есть [оно так называется](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/index.php).
2. На самом деле, это документация по работе с классами и методами движка Битрикса, которая позволяет писать свои собственные скрипты, которые тем или иным способом взаимодействуют с информацией в базе данных.
3. Если вам требуется обновлять не очень часто не очень много товара (до 100 наименований), то API вам подойдет.

   - Вам потребуется обновлять [несколько параметров элемента инфоблока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/index.php), который представляет товар.
   - Также вам потребуется сохранять картинку через `CFile::MakeFileArray` -- это несложно, но рекомендую ее предварительно обработать.
4. Если вам нужно обновлять много товаров часто, то, к сожалению, просто это не решается.

   - Нужно изучать [структуру таблиц модуля информационных блоков](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/fields.php)
   - А также структуру таблиц, с которыми работает тот самый `CFile`

Удачи в этом нелегком деле.